# Why is isFinite(undefined) != isFinite(null)?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

Why is the value for undefined considered Finite in javascript while null is not?

This is a very basic question, which has thwarted my googlefoo (too much noise).

```
isFinite(undefined); // false
isFinite(null); // true
```

I do not understand as I would expect null and undefined to be handled in the same manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `Number(null) === 0`.

http://es5.github.io/#x9.3

Comment: You sir are quick. Thank you much for satisfying my curiosity!

Answer (score 1):

> isFinite (number)
>
> Returns false if the argument coerces to NaN, +∞, or −∞, and otherwise returns true.

`isFinite` convert input using `Number()` and:

```
Number(undefined); //== NaN
Number(null); //== 0
```

that is the reason undefined is false and null is true for isFinite.

If you try:

```
isFinite(!undefined); // true
```

because undefined is NaN and on negating it it converted to 1 which is finite.