# Why does `isFinite(null) === true`?

Tags: javascript, null

The following are examples that make sense to me.

```
isFinite(5) // true - makes sense to me, it is a number and it is finite
  typeof 5 // "number"
isFinite(Infinity) // false - makes sense for logical reasons
  typeof Infinity // "number"
isFinite(document) // false - makes sense as well, it's not even a number
  typeof document // "object"
```

The following is where I get confused.

```
isFinite(null) // true - Wait what? Other non-number objects returned false. I see no reason?
  typeof null // "object"
```

I just don't see the reasoning behind this. 
What I'd like is the most low-level answer possible. 
I think `null` is being converted to 0, why? What other impacts does this have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is isFinite(undefined) != isFinite(null)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254205/why-is-isfiniteundefined-isfinitenull)

Comment: Low-level response: in Math (and therefore in JavaScript, ostensibly), when something has null value, it has an empty value, or a value of zero. Zero is a finite number. Therefore, null is finite. Unless you can be the first to somehow find the inverse of infinity, I doubt this will ever change.

Comment: @TylerH that was a good way to word it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing @Jhawins. Full disclosure: I am NOT in the mathematics field, so I'm not an expert.

Comment: Disagree Tyler, null != 0 in Math, "null has not a value of 0". In Statistics and Probability fields it's an important difference. Other example: to mark `x` in a graph 2D (x-y axis); x = 0 is a point, you make a dot on the line 0, x = null = ∅, that is the absence of value, there's no point, no dot.. Maybe JS, it's correct.. but not in Math..

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo Here we have some clever wordplay application, where "no value" is used to mean "absence of value" and they are interchangeable. This is where null = 0 comes from. Whether something has null value or value of 0 should result in the same answer, but I'm not a mathematician, so if you can explain how this is not so (in Statistics and Probabilities, for example), I'd be interested to learn.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238627 http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134861
Javascript by definition, parses null to 0. But it's not true say the generally null = 0.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The ECMAScript spec (5.1) defines `isFinite` to act as such:

> isFinite (number)
>
> Returns false if the argument coerces to NaN, +∞, or −∞, and otherwise returns true.
>
> If ToNumber(number) is NaN, +∞, or −∞, return false.
>
> Otherwise, return true.

In other words, `isFinite` is calling [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) on whatever's passed in, and then comparing it to either pos/neg infinity or NaN.

In JavaScript (note the use of `!=` instead of the more common `!==`, causing the type cast):

```
function isFinite(someInput) {
  return !isNaN(someInput) &&
    someInput != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY &&
    someInput != Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
}
```

(As noted in [the comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489966/why-does-isfinitenull-true/22490055#comment34220196_22490055), `someInput != NaN` is not needed, as `NaN` is defined to not be equivalent to everything, including itself.)

Now, why is `null` converted to zero (as opposed to `undefined`)?  As [TylerH says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489966/why-does-isfinitenull-true/22490055#comment34215081_22489966) in the comments, `null` means that a value exists, but is empty.  The mathematical representation of this is 0.  `undefined` means that there isn't a value there, so we get `NaN` when trying to call `ToNumber` on it.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.5

However, ECMAScript 6 is bringing along a non-converting `isFinite` as a property of `Number`.  Douglas Crockford suggested it here: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:number.isfinite

Comment: Crockford's *isFinite* is inconsistent thought: `Crockford_isFinite(Number(null)) === true`. ;-)

Comment: Why bother with the `someInput != NaN`? All values in JavaScript are defined as being unequal to NaN, including NaN.

Comment: @ChrisHayes To be explicitly like what the standard says.  It's less efficient, but more clear.

Comment: You should put a comment in the code with a little clarification about this one. Leaving this as is can lead inexpert coders to errors. It would be good to use the default function `isNaN`, commenting out the `someInput != NaN` part, and spending two words in explaining why `NaN` is dynamically generated and why it is unequal to `NaN` itself. Just suggestions, though.

Comment: @LightStyle Done, I kept the function the same but added a comment below.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 I am no expert in JS, but I believe even with the explanation, `someInput != NaN` is still wrong. When `someInput` actually is NaN then the function will return `true`, since `NaN != NaN` is true. I think the first condition should be `someInput == someInput`, which will be false in case of NaN. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 14):

From MDN:

> The global isFinite() function determines whether the passed value is
>   a finite number. If needed, the parameter is first converted to a
>   number.

So, it's converted to a number...

```
isFinite(null)
isFinite(+null) //convert to a number
isFinite(0) // true because +null or Number(null) = 0
```

The spec says that the global `isFinite()` method will forcibly convert the parameter to a number.

You could, however, use (at your own risk) the EcmaScript 6 spec's [`Number.isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) which doesn't perform this conversion.

```
Number.isFinite(null) // false
```

Or, like lodash and underscore do it...

```
var _.isFinite = function(obj) {
  return isFinite(obj) && !isNaN(parseFloat(obj));
};
```

Comment: Why is it "needed"? I can see that this is what is returned already, I'm asking why :P

Comment: @Jhawins: Because that's what the spec says. Anything else is opinion.

Comment: I'd love to accept your answer, but look at what @SomeKittens has cooked up below... You beat him by 1 minute, but that was clever. Still 1 minute till I can accept though :P

Comment: The underscore way is just an inefficient way of writing `typeof obj === 'number'`.

Comment: I believe you, but why is that? Any tests to back it up?

Comment: @brbcoding—here you go: [*operator vs method*](http://jsperf.com/operator-vs-method). The typeof operator is about 50 to 100 times faster in Safari and Firefox and about 300 times faster in mobile Safari. However, the *isNaN* method accepts strings and objects whose *toString* method returns a suitable value whereas *typeof* doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

[`isFinite`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.5) calls [`ToNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) on its argument. So

```
> Number(null)
0
> Number(document)
NaN
> isFinite(0)
true
> isFinite(NaN)
false

> isFinite(null)
true
> isFinite(document)
false
```

Answer (score 5):

Because, if you say

`Number(null) === 0` which is finite

See [To Number Conversions](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)

Which says that, for argument type `null` result is `+0`

Answer (score 4):

`isFinite` typecasts it's argument to a number, if it's not already a number. Essentially you have `isFinite(Number(null))` and `Number(null) === 0`. Which is finite.

Answer (score 3):

Beside `null`, you find these [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/Shf7a/1/) interesting too:

```
alert(isFinite(' '));  //true
alert(isFinite(''));  //true
alert(isFinite(null));  //true
alert(isFinite(!undefined));  //true
```

In JavaScript implicit conversion take place, This conversion try to convert bool to integer when comparing numbers with boolean, or number to string when comparing string with numbers. If you treat any data-type as number it implicitly converted to number so all above cases return zero which is finite. [See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shf7a/2/)

If you try `Number(undefined)` it give you a `NaN` on negate this would produce a 1 which is finite.

Comment: also `alert(isFinite(true)); //true` as true is treated as 1