# Why isFinite(NaN) is false?

Tags: javascript, nan

Since NaN defines Not a Number so it is neither a finite nor an infinite quantity, shouldn't the answer be undefined or unverified or something similar to that instead of false?

Comment: `"potato"` is not a finite number, so `isFinite("potato")` is `false`. `NaN` is not a finite number, so `isFinite(NaN)` is false. Just because `isFinite(n) == false` doesn't mean `n == Infinity`.

Comment: Actually, this explains it better -> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489966/why-does-isfinitenull-true**, *Returns false if the argument coerces to NaN, +∞, or −∞, and otherwise returns true*

Comment: Let me ask you, is the word "word" finite? I don't know too, because it isn't even a number, therefore it's neither finite or infinite. (Technical details: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

`isFinite` returns a boolean response, `true` for finite numbers and `false` for everything else.

Comment: This isn't true. It doesn't just return true for finite numbers; actually it returns true as well for strings/arrays that can be casted to a (finite) number.

Comment: a number in quotes is still a number in javascript-landia, I purposefully left out data types in my response.  Being pedantic in a weakly typed language about data types seems a little silly to me.